# Next js 13.4 video streaming

Tags: next.js, video-streaming, next.js13

I have a problem with video streaming in nextJS as a full-stack project.
I used the new GET method strategy to get the streams in next.
here is my front code that request the API to fetch streams.

```
        <video  className="w-full rounded-lg" controls  autoPlay = {true}>
          <source src={`/api/video/${film._id}`} type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
```

and this is the API that I request

```
import connectDB from "@/config/connectDB"
import { Film } from "@/models"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import  fs from "fs"

const CHUNK_SIZE = 1000000 // 1MB
connectDB()

async function getVideoStream (req, id) {
  const range = req.headers.get("range")

  if(!range) {
    return new Response("Range header missing", { status: 400 })
  }

  const film = await Film.findById(id)
  const filePath = film.storage
  const stat = fs.statSync(filePath)
  const fileSize = stat.size
  console.log("fileSize", fileSize)

  const chunkStart = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, "")) || 0
  const chunkEnd = Math.min(chunkStart + CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize - 1)

  const contentLength = chunkEnd - chunkStart + 1

  const header = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${chunkStart}-${chunkEnd}/${fileSize}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": contentLength.toString(),
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
  }

  const videStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { chunkStart, chunkEnd })
  return new Response(videStream, { status: 206, headers: header })
}

export async function GET(request, { params }) {

  try {
    return getVideoStream(request, params?.id)

  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 400 })
  }

}
```

the result only shows the video size and doesn't play anything.

Comment: _"The result only shows the video size and doesn't play anything"_ How can we test that? Also (using Chrome browser) if you paste your link `/api/video/${film._id}` in a **new tab** does it show a video, or does it download a file, or does it show an error message?

Comment: no, it just says the range is not set and there is no video display in the browser, I think it is because of streams that should be pip with a response.
https://blog.logrocket.com/build-video-streaming-server-node/
all the code is the same as this doc the only place that is different is fs.pip(res)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I found the solution many websites I searched but this implementation was the best it streams my video in front side also you can implement this without calling API, with ssr.

```
import connectDB from "@/config/connectDB"
import { Film } from "@/models"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import fs from "fs"

const CHUNK_SIZE = 1000000 // 1MB
connectDB()

async function getVideoStream(req, id) {
  const range = req.headers.get("range")

  if (!range) {
    return new Response("Range header missing", { status: 400 })
  }

  const film = await Film.findById(id)
  console.log("backend film", film)
  const filePath = film.storage
  const stat = fs.statSync(filePath)
  const fileSize = stat.size

  const chunkStart = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, "")) || 0
  const chunkEnd = Math.min(chunkStart + CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize - 1)

  const contentLength = chunkEnd - chunkStart + 1

  const headers = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${chunkStart}-${chunkEnd}/${fileSize}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": contentLength.toString(),
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
  }

  const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, { start: chunkStart, end: chunkEnd })
  const response = new Response(videoStream, { status: 206, headers })

  return response
}

export async function GET(request, { params }) {
  try {
    return await getVideoStream(request, params?.id)
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 400 })
  }
}
```